# Arduino Custom Neon Light Control lighting effect

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to build a custom neon light and after some research I've figured out the light source is LED RGB strip and it can be controlled by Arduino LED Controller but how can I make it like this as in  [the video on this page](https://yeoneon.co.uk/colour-changing-full-colour-custom-neon-signs/)?

Answer (score 0):

The effect is made by using individually addressable RGB leds.

A popular type of this kind of LED is known as the [ws2812](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf). Which is available both as a seperate LED and on strips and panels.

Both [Sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ws2812-breakout-hookup-guide/) and [adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/the-magic-of-neopixels) provide Arduino tutorials and libraries for controlling these kind of LEDs as well as the LEDs themselves.